# c++ Pure virtual functions dependent on derived classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, derived-class, pure-virtual

I am working on a bounding box/collision detection system and I am using different types of bounding volumes, id like all the bounding volumes to derive the same base class and then using pure virtual functions forcing all derived classes to implement basic functions like

- `isCollidingWith(BoudingBox)`

But here is what giving me trouble: I wan't them to implement a function for every `BoudingVolume` type. So if I have a bounding box and a bounding sphere, both the sphere class and the box class should implement

- `isCollidingWith(BoundingBox)`
- `isCollidingWith(BoundingSphere)`

If i then create a new BoundingVolume like `BoundingCylinder` (by deriving from the base class), i want the compiler to throw an error until BoundingBox and BoundingSphere has implemented the `isCollidingWith` function for the new `Cylinder` type (and ofc until the `Cylinder` has implemented the `isCollidingWith` for the `Box`, `Sphere` and the `Cylinder`.

Im not sure on how to go about implementing this, but I thought about using CRTPs.
Is this even possible?

Comment: All you have to do is put a pure virtual function (i.e. `virtual bool isCollidingWith(BoundingCylinder) = 0;`into your base class, and you'll get a compiler error until all the derived classes add an implementation.

Comment: This is impossible to do automatically (unlike with @TonyDelroy's manual answer), because the compiler won't keep track of all the types that derive from `BoundingVolume`, so it can't know that. I think it's easy enough to solve without that, though, if all your classes are convex; I'd need to check more carefully to be sure, though.

Comment: Add the pure virtual function and see what happens when you recompile. **If** there's a problem **then** ask about that problem. In addition you may want to read about things like "double dispatch" and "visitor pattern".

Comment: Searching "double dispatch" solved my question, just like n.m. said, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to concoct such a thing with CRTP

```
class BoundingBox;
class BoundingSphere;

class Shape
{
    public:
        virtual bool isIntersecting(const BoundingBox&) const = 0;
        virtual bool isIntersecting(const BoundingSphere&) const = 0;
};

class BoundingVolumeBase
{
    public:
        virtual bool checkIntersection(const Shape&) const = 0;
        virtual ~BoundingVolumeBase();
};

template<class Derived>
class BoundingVolume : public BoundingVolumeBase
{
        bool checkIntersection(const Shape& shape) const override
        {
            return shape.isIntersecting (static_cast<const Derived&>(*this));
        }
};

class BoundingBox : public BoundingVolume<BoundingBox> {
    // ...
};

class BoundingSphere : public BoundingVolume<BoundingSphere> {
    // ...
};
```

Now if we invent a new kind of `BoundingVolume`, it will not compile until a new function is added to `Shape`.

```
class BoundingCylinder : public BoundingVolume<BoundingCylinder> {
    // ...
};

BoundingCylinder bc; // <-- this will not compile
```

It is not necessary to do it this way. Any method that uses virtual functions as the sole kind of type-based dispatch will work (you will likely end up with something roughly equivalent to the above anyway). If you depend on `typeid` or on a custom type identifier, you may encounter problems though.

The downside of this method is mutual dependence of class `Shape` and *all* concrete kinds of `BoundingVolume`.

Answer (score 4):

When you make **pure virtual function** in base class, then it is **compulsory** for derived class for its implementation, if derived class doesn't implement it then compiler will give you an **error**. so you don't have to take care whether the pure virtual functions are implemented or not.